# Plone: 504 Gateway Time-out renaming a folder

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I must rename a folder (title and short name / id) containing a lot of contents. It seems to take a lot of time and I receive `504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time.`

Is there a solution for a quick item renaming? (Maybe with a script?) Can you give me a hint to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming is going to index the folder's contents recursively. Try doing it from a direct ZEO client connection, e.g. on port 8080, rather than through a web server proxy (nginx / Apache).

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem with Plone. As Kim said it uncatalogs and catalogs every item in this folder. This includes heavy indexes like `SearchableText`.

I wrote a part of [`ftw.copymovepatches`](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.copymovepatches), which significantly improves renaming and moving of large structures.

The idea is to NOT uncatalog and catalog all items, but reindex only the necessary indexes, like `id`, `path`, `allowedRolesAndUsers`, etc.

On average, if you have the patch installed, you gain 70% - 90%.
Of course this depends on your setup, but you should feel it ;-)

Comment: That's a very cool add-on. I noticed the README has a spot for the PR you were planning to make to get it into Plone... is that still an objective? Another way we handle slow move/copy/rename in Castle https://castlecms.io is we move those operations to a queue so they run in the background and notify the user when they're complete.

Comment: I was not able to do it so far, sry. The package itself also grew, since the first release.